# Изображение на весь экран для всех Android устройств

Tags: android, xml, изображения

Создал Splash screen для своего приложения, реализовал по [примеру](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/). Требуется, что бы изображение было на весь экран, учитывая что оно загружается в xml.
Поскольку реализация подразумевает использование темы, то изображение подгружается в xml файле, в следствии чего нет возможности свободно менять его width и height.
Возможно этот вопрос можно решить по аналогу с иконкой: создать несколько изображений с разными разрешениями, но тут тоже возникает вопрос, если опираться на: ldpi, hdpi и так далее, то для телефона мы можем иметь изображение нормального разрешения, а для планшета - маленькое.
Прочитал это [руководство](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html),  но полного решения проблемы не увидел, ибо так и не понял сколько же нужно создать папок ресурсов, что бы покрыть все экраны, и в итоге получится ли.
Уточненный вопрос. Как сделать, что бы загруженное в xml изображение, на любом устройстве отображалось во весь экран.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте свою разметку, под SplashScreen, выставите нужные параметры которые соответствуют вашим запросам, растянуть, обрезать, увеличить, выровнять etc. Используйте её при показе.

Вот пример который выставит относительно границ картинки:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Как вариант подготовить, нужные форматы картинки для разных устройств и заливать его в background, отрегулировать при это сам контейнер, чтоб не допустить искажение.

" **+** картинка будет 100% fullscreen на любых device

" **-**  возможное низкое качество на device  с высоким разрешением (это вы должны предусмотреть)

Comment: Это решает проблему, но тогда теряется суть самого Splash Screen. Если мы создаем его как Activity, и загружаем туда layout, то будет пауза, пока это все произойдет, и все это время будет показываться белый экран.
Если же мы делаем эту процедуру через тему, то отображение мгновенное, что и требуется, но появился такой болезненный вопрос с изображением.

Comment: По поводу background, а как сделать что бы изображение было на 100% fullscrenn. Надо что бы оно покрывало весь background? Что-то еще требуется настроить?

Comment: Адаптируйте переход от системного (белого фона) к вашей разметке SplashScrenn, изменив его. как вариант поставьте ваш же drawable

Comment: А можете подсказать как это делается, а то не находил такое решение в Google.

Comment: Так у вас пример на этом основан. Вы создаете drawable, потом замещаете Ваше системное  окно <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>  но вопрос который вы задали не решается данным примером.

Comment: Я вас до конца не понял.
У меня на данном этапе - загрузка xml разметки, в которой есть изображение. Что мне требуется изменить, что бы грузилось изображение full-screen?

Comment: Что же, благодарен за ответы, буду пробовать.

Comment: Чтоб грузилось в фул скрин, я дал ответ выше. А чтоб не было белого экрана, необходимо, изменить системное окно. Ваш пример показывает как это делать, вам просто необходимо придумать, как. Я к примеру задавал gradient фон, потом ставил анимацию появления логотипа, смотрится отлично. Всё зависит от Ваших пожеланий, я же не знаю что у Вас там за картинка, логотип или ещё что-то.

Comment: Хм, надо будет попробовать вариант с анимацией, спасибо.